# FB App Channel file. ChannelUrl not loading?

Tags: facebook-apps, channel

I have a Canvas app on Facebook that simply displays a page hosted on our external site. Working just fine.

What I have noticed in Firefox is there is a continuous loading and error being reported in Firebug:

> GET http://0-68.channel.facebook.com/pull?channel=p_...1&partition=1&clientid=3744ab1f&cb=b3di&idle=287
>
> 200 Aborted
>
> 39.86s

This attempt to load always takes around 40s, and is retried instantly after failure. I have also tried loading the above URL by itself, but this just times out with a "Connection Reset" message.

Is this something to do with my channelUrl directive in the SDK setup? I have this setup as follows:

```
var channel_url         = "http://mysite.com/facebook/channel/"; // Aside from the domain, this is the actual final url.
var app_id              = "blahblahblah";


// Initialize the facebook object
FB.init({
    appId: app_id, // From the globals set up at the top of this page
    channelUrl : channel_url, 
    cookie: true,
    xfbml: true,
    oauth: true
});
```

The channel file only has this in it:

```
<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

But I have also tried asynchronous loading the js too.

If I load http://mysite.com/facebook/channel/ in a browser, all is fine.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Starting to think this is either a Facebook or Firebug issue. I have installed a couple of similar apps, and they do exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook's JS SDK does long-polling for event updates. If no updates are available the connection will eventually time out, which you will see as Aborted in Firebug.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Is there a source you know of for this?

Answer (score -1):

*copy and pasted from another location

These requests are the HTTP Long-Polling requests. I've only had the Facebook site open for a few minutes and I'm not really monitoring activity but it looks like:

- Facebook are using HTTP Long-Polling where open connections are marked as 'pending'
- HTTP Long-Poll requests stay open for 40 seconds and after that time if there is no activity that request closes and a new one opens.
- If a response is sent (server to client) within the 40 seconds the connection closes (well, that's how HTTP Long-Polling works)